# how to extract features from this image ? what are the suitable features to be selected?

Tags: image-processing, software-implementation

I have this image:

[image]

After many preprocessing operations, I obtained this image

[image]

my goal is implementing one to many matching on my images for recognition purpose,i have 250 image for 50 persons (5 image/person) ,they are represented as: 0001hv1,0001hv2,0001hv3,0001hv4,0001hv5,0002hv1,.......  ,  now:

i ask if i can consider the preprocessed image as a feature vector in order to use dimensionality reduction algorithm such as PCA or SIFT or any other that enable me to do matching or not ?if it is not ,what are features may be suitable for creating feature vector?

finally , i wish that my question is obvious , if it is not, i need only to know ,  which one i need to implement on preprocessed image , feature extraction or dimensionality reduction . sorry but my english language is not very good.

regards to all

Comment: Lets first define what exactly the information is you wish to extract?

Comment: i need to work on this image which represent veins of human hand by extracting specific features and then use these features for matching and recognition purposes .

Comment: Replace the link with the actual image - you can add images to the post

Comment: i added the link for original image...thanks

Comment: Again, what "matching" and "recognition" purposes? Do you want to compare persons? Anomalies in the shape? Estimate the size? Et cetera.

Comment: recognition means recognize persons based on their hand veins image by comparison and matching with the samples stored in database so i need to obtain feature vector from each image ,but until now i dont know which feature will be suitable for my project.thanks

Comment: This sounds more like a question about anatomy than about signal processing...

Comment: Are you trying to match vein networks ?

Comment: no , i tried but still now i don't know if i can matching without feature extraction stage.please , help me if you have any idea about this

Comment: ruaa, first is - much more clarity appears by comments than the question. So i strongly suggest that you edit your question to accommodate all this information that would look very good.

Comment: I guess, i have try to answer some of your questions in past which appears to be for the same project. But only from this comments do i now understand things slightly better. Before you judge *which features are good* and *how to extract them* -ask a very basic question: If you would have given set of images to human that belongs to class1 and others that are not class1 - how would humans have identified them? - essentially what information is responsible to make the qualification work? That is nothing but feature.

Comment: -1. ruaa, you added images appropriately. But as far as other information is concerned, you have not amended your answer appropriately. See my above comment - and i have asked a question.  Please note that `feature_extraction` and `PCA` are not magical things! You have not put any clarity on *what is required to be done*. Consider reading [Pattern Classification -Duda &Hart](http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471056693.html)

Comment: @Dipan Mehta.i edited my question , i am so sorry but if i understoodnd your qestion , you means how my image for each person represents and this is added in my edition to the question,  if it is not your question ,can  you illustrate more ?please.sorry again.thanks

Comment: @ruaa You have now asked several questions on the same topic, each one only a little different from the previous. This cannot go on. Please take the time to think through your problem fully (_think_, not _solve_) and _then_ post a question here when you get stuck, with full specifics. I'm inclined to close this within the next day if the question is not improved with details

Comment: @yoda.edition done again, my experience is little and my english too , this make me unable to put good question.please,inform me if there is something bad in question.thanks

Comment: can u share the data set. So that i can find solution. if possible can u say where u get this data set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> i ask if i can consider the preprocessed image as a feature vector in order to use dimensionality reduction algorithm such as PCA

You mean applying PCA to this preprocessed image directly? I'm almost certain that can't work. PCA makes sense if you have lots of samples that are linearly dependent. You have few samples that are linearly independent.

> or SIFT

SIFT is not a dimensionality reduction algorithm but a feature extraction algorithm. So to apply SIFT, you would usually search for "keypoints" (e.g. line endings, T-junctions) and SIFT would create a feature vector that describes the image in the neighborhood of each keypoint. Problem is, thanks to your preprocessing, there's not much to say about each keypoint besides "it's a line ending" or "it's a t-junction".

> or any other that enable me to do matching or not ?if it is not ,what are features may be suitable for creating feature vector?

Many, but I can't tell you which features will give the same values for the same persons. You'll probably have to implement a few different approaches, test them on a reasonably sized set of test images (e.g. 100-1000 different images of each of your persons), and see how high the recognition rate is. If you only test on the 5 images you have now, you can't know if your algorithm has a 0.1% error rate or a 20% error rate.

That said, here are a few ideas you might try:

1. Find the line endings and junctions. Then do point cloud matching to compare different skeletons.
2. Use the preprocessed images as features directly. To compare two images, take each point in image A in turn and measure the distance to the closest point in image B. (This can be efficiently calculated by calculating a distance transform on one image.) The mean or median distance might be a good similarity measure. Align both images to minimize this measure.
3. Use a hough transform to find (almost) straight lines, then match those (matching lines is similar to point matching)

But to be honest, I don't think this problem can be solved by a beginner, even with help from Stackexchange. I hope I don't sound patronizing, but my real advice is: start with a simpler problem. Get a few introductory books on image processing/computer vision. Get comfortable with Matlab or Mathematica. Play around with image filters, template matching algorithms, image transformations and so on. Read [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html). Find more and more advanced problems that you can solve on your own. Unfortunately, that's the only way to get experience, and you need experience to solve problems like these.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can try using [template matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) on the resulting image of your image processing operations. So you have a database of these images, there comes a new image in, you process it, and you find the best match by laying the new image over all the images in the database (using a certain distance measure between all the white pixels).
2. You can also try to extract lines of your processed image, and represent the image with the starting point of the line, the length and the slope of the line. Using this as a feature vector, you can also compute a distance between a new image and the database.

You can also combine the two, by using the second approach as a first selection step, because template matching can be quite computationally expensive.